# How can one seamlessly utilize two computers via dual monitors and a single keyboard / mouse?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, kvm-switch, remoteapp

I have a Toshiba laptop with docking station connected to two LCD monitors.

I have a Dell workstations currently not attached to any monitors.

I'd like to use the laptop for general office work and the workstation for application development.

The possibilities I have thus far are:

1. Setup four monitors - two for each computer (this is really a non-option).
2. Purchase a (fairly) expensive dual monitor KVM.
3. Use RemoteApp to utilize the workstation for the horsepower but in a seamless way (but this seems to be a non-option since the workstation is running Windows 7, not a server OS, and I'm not looking to spend money on a server OS).
4. Use Remote Desktop (this works, but it isn't seamless. There is always the feeling of being on two computers at once, so its really a non-option).

Other ideas or variations on these? Thanks!

Comment: Synergy : http://synergy-foss.org.

Answer (score 8):

[Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) would allow you to use one monitor on each and switch between machines. It synchronizes you clipboard between machines which is great and even allows you to drag and drop files between machines. Most people that I know with this issue use Synergy.

I've also setup a single monitor KVM in the past and went dual monitor on one machine, and then used the KVM to swap to the second machine when I need to work on that. That setup works better if you have a primary-secondary setup though.